# How to Implement Copy to Clipboard Button in JSF?

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, web-applications

I currently have a JSF webapp and I have an output field that my managed bean sets the value for, and I want to ass a button for the user to copy the output text straight to their clipboard (aka ctrl-c/cmd-c).

I've been doing some research, but I'm a bit confused, some are suggesting this cannot be done.

So my question is...can this be done? And if so, any suggestions on how to implement it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cannot be done using javascript alone. You can do it with a flash plugin though. Check out zeroclipboard: http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

Comment: Yea, this is what I found before.  I don't think I would want users to require Flash for my webapp to function properly so that was my reservation.

Thank you!